# Java custom exception

Tags: java, exception

I have **successfully** **implemented** a **custom exception** using below code

**CarNotFoundException.Java**

```
 public class CarNotFoundException extends Exception 
       {        
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public CarNotFoundException(String msg) {
                super(msg);
            }
        }
```

**Car.Java**

```
public static CarProvider getInstanceByProvider(String provider) throws CarNotFoundException {
        if(!provider.equals(Constants.BMW || Constants.B||Constants.C{ 
            throw new CarNotFoundException("Car Not Found");
            }   
        return carProvider;
    }
```

**CarTest.java**

```
        try 
        {
          carProvider = Car.getInstanceByProvider(provider);    
        } catch (CarNotFoundException e) {
            e.printstacktrace();
        }
```

**What I want to do ?**

Instead of `e.printStackTrace();` when I call`e.getMessage()`,
I get nothing(blank).

How I can make custom `e.getMessage()` ?

**Edit** : I got my answer, I missed  `System.out.println()`

Thanks for helping..!

Comment: whats this ProviderNotFoundException ? is it custom?

Comment: Your custom exception seems to be `CarNotFoundException`, but you're catching a `ProviderNotFoundException`. The `e.getMessage()` will work just fine with the code in `CarNotFoundException`.

Comment: wish you said it sooner. i have already post an answer

Comment: Are you sure you are calling e.getMessage() ? There is no problem with the code you are showing above.

Comment: `e.getMessage()` will get the message. Are you printing it? `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Comment: Thanks, I missed `System.out.println` ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override getMessage() method in your custom exception

```
public class CarNotFoundException extends Exception 
{        
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     public String message;

     public CarNotFoundException(String msg) {
         this.message = msg;
     }

  // Overrides Exception's getMessage()
     @Override
     public String getMessage(){
         return message;
     }
 }
```

Comment: tried this but not working `public class CarNotFoundException extends Exception {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 private String message;
 
 public CarNotFoundException(String message) {
  
  this.message = message;
 }
 
 @Override
 public String getMessage() {
  return message; 
 }
}`

Comment: What message you get?

Comment: I get nothing, blank message

Comment: Write System.out.print(e.getMessage());

Comment: Thanks, I missed `System.out.println` ):

Comment: This is totally unnecessary, as similar code already exists in `Throwable`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't get you point, Can you please explain? Does it mean Overriding getMessage() is unnecessary?

Comment: @PVR yes, that is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @PVR Exception's super class(Throwable) already have getMessage() method implemented